# How to get all features in current extent

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I like to add text information to each feature in the shown map extent in my MapControl/PageLayoutControl. Adding the text is not a problem, but I couldn't find a way on how to get the features.

Is there a way to get all features in a layer that are in the current map extent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at:

```
Dim pEnv As IEnvelope
 pEnv = pAv.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.VisibleBounds
```

Setting the envelope = to the activeview visible bounds.  You will then have to define a spatial filter, find the specific feature class, and set that to a featurecursor to grab all the features.

Comment: Thanks artwork21. Thats the trick. See my answer for implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to artwork21 I could solve this like this:

```
IMap map = this._mapControl.ActiveView.FocusMap;
IEnvelope envelope = _mapControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.VisibleBounds;

IGeoFeatureLayer featLayer = myLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
if (featLayer != null)
{
IFeatureClass featureClass = featLayer.FeatureClass;
System.String shapeFieldName = featureClass.ShapeFieldName;
// Create a new spatial filter and use the new envelope as the geometry
ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
spatialFilter.Geometry = envelope;
spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelEnvelopeIntersects;
spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference(shapeFieldName, map.SpatialReference);
spatialFilter.GeometryField = shapeFieldName;

// Do the search
IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
return featureCursor;
```

Comment: Won't the envelope be larger than what is visible if IDisplayTransformation.Rotation is not zero?