# Get all features in extent not working correctly in PageLayoutControl

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I want to get all features in the current extent of my PageLayoutControl's ActiveView. I got it working for a MapControl as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/how-to-get-all-features-in-current-extent).

With my PageLayoutControl it seems that I don't get the correct extent. When I fill the found features it looks like this:

[image]

Here is how I get the features:

```
Dictionary<String, IFeatureCursor> featureCursors = new Dictionary<String, IFeatureCursor>();
IMap map = this._pageLayoutControl.ActiveView.FocusMap;

// Get ActiveView from MapFrame
IActiveView tmpActiveView = null;
IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer)_pageLayoutControl.PageLayout;
graphicsContainer.Reset();
IElement element = graphicsContainer.Next();
while (element != null)
{
  if (element is IMapFrame)
  {
    IMapFrame mapFrame = (IMapFrame)element;
    tmpActiveView = (IActiveView)mapFrame.Map;
    break;
  }
  element = graphicsContainer.Next();
}
if (tmpActiveView == null)
  return featureCursors;

IEnvelope envelope = this._pageLayoutControl.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.VisibleBounds; // FittedBounds;
// PageLayout has no SpatialReference. So use the View of the MapFrame 
IPoint pointMax = tmpActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint((System.Int32)envelope.XMax, (System.Int32)envelope.YMax);
IPoint pointMin = tmpActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint((System.Int32)envelope.XMin, (System.Int32)envelope.YMin);
envelope.XMax = pointMax.X;
envelope.YMax = pointMax.Y;
envelope.XMin = pointMin.X;
envelope.YMin = pointMin.Y;

// Get Features in all layers
for (int iFeatLayer = 0; iFeatLayer < _pageLayoutControl.ActiveView.FocusMap.LayerCount; iFeatLayer++)
{ 
  ILayer thisLayer = _pageLayoutControl.ActiveView.FocusMap.Layer[iFeatLayer];
  IGeoFeatureLayer featLayer = thisLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
  if (featLayer != null)
  {
    IFeatureClass featureClass = featLayer.FeatureClass;
    System.String shapeFieldName = featureClass.ShapeFieldName;

    // Create a new spatial filter and use the new envelope as the geometry
    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
    spatialFilter.Geometry = envelope;
    spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelEnvelopeIntersects;
    spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference(shapeFieldName, map.SpatialReference);
    spatialFilter.GeometryField = shapeFieldName;

    // Do the search
    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
    featureCursors.Add(thisLayer.Name, featureCursor);
  }
}
return featureCursors;
```

What did I miss? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out: The IEnvelope I got was the wrong one. The `Extent` of the MapFrame's `ActiveView` is the one I needed. So that part should look like this:

```
IEnvelope envelope = tmpActiveView.Extent;
```

The `IEnvelope` already has the spatial reference, so the 'translation' via `ToMapPoint` is no longer needed.